# TypeError: user.comparePassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I don't know why I am getting this error. TypeError: user.comparePassword is not a function.

I installed all the dependencies. Linked the APP to to all the libraries. 
I tried to use Postman to retrieve the data, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "name": "e-commerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.4.2",
    "ejs-mate": "^2.3.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}


var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var engine = require('ejs-mate');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(session);
var passport = require('passport');



var secret = require('./config/secret');
var User = require("./models/user.js");


var app = express();

mongoose.connect(secret.database, function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to database");
  }
});
//Middleware
//add how to use static page
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: secret.secretKey,
  store: new MongoStore({url: secret.database, autoReconnect: true})
}));


app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


var mainRoutes = require('./routes/main');
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
app.use(mainRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);

app.listen(secret.port, function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Server running on port " + secret.port);
});




var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user._id);
});



passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});


//middlewear

passport.use('local-login', new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
  User.find({email: email}, function(err, user){
    if (err) return done(err);

    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user has been found'));
    }

    if(!user.comparePassword(password)){
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Opps! Wrong Password Pal'));
    }


    return done(null, user);
  });
}));

//custom function to validate
exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
  if( req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/login');
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What exactly is `.comparePassword`?

You get `User` from `./models/user.js` (I presume it's a mongo model, but we cannot see it), then you call `.find` (if it's really Mongo it should return you an array, for one result you should use `.findOne`) and then you get your result in `user` variable and try to call some method `.comparePassword()` for your result, that in your case definetly is `undefined`...

Try to add `console.log(user)` before `user.comparePassword` and you will see exactly what you get.

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding.
It returned this object
[ { _id: 57854611fdb264c0512030a7,
    password: '$2a$10$KtN9q6sk5uoLaOcNyPeKpuXAAmtBzcN/VqY42K.LspmGWeaeHMTX.',
    email: 'hamster007@gmail.com',
    __v: 0,
    history: [],
    profile: { picture: '', name: 'Hamster' } } ]

That's the user and information I inputted for Sign-up.

Comment: Sure, it's array. Property or method like `.comparePassword` will always be `undefined`. If you will request `.findOne` you will get object (the same you have as an element of your array).
Google search showed me that you got this `.comparePassword` from mongoDB blog example - you have either really define it in your mongo model. Or (I prefer this approach) you could define your password comparsion function not in model but in your validation function or even in separate module.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter/blob/master/server/models/user.js

Answer (score 0):

```
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField:"email",
      passwordField:"password",
      passReqToCallback:true,
 
   },
   function(req,username,password,done){
   User.findOne({
   email:username,
   },function(err,user){
    if(err)
    {   console.log(err);
        return done(err);}
       
        if(!user)
        return done(null,false,{message:"These user is not exits !"});
        user.authenticate(password, function(err,users,passwordError){
            console.log(users);
            if(passwordError){
                console.log(err)
              return  done(null,false,{message:"password is wrong"})
            } else if(users) {
                console.log(`correct password ${users}`)
              return   done(null,users);
               
            }
        })
    })
  }));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and this hack solved it for me

In your middleware **replace**

```
if(!user.comparePassword(password)){
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Opps! Wrong Password Pal'));
    }
```

**with**

```
const passwordOk = await User.findByCredentials(email, password);
      if (!passwordOk) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username or password' });
      }
```

and in your `./models/user.js` page after userSchema, add this code;

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if (!isMatch) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    return user
}
```

Run the code, this should work

Answer (score 0):

in your ./model/user.js file **define comparePassword** function and pass it two of your parameters 1.user input password 2.encrypt password
this is how I solved it in my case

```
module.exports.comparePassword = async (inputPassword, hashedPassword) => {
try {
    return await bcryptjs.compare(inputPassword, hashedPassword);
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Comparison failed", error);
}
```

};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your mongo schema, if the function is defined incorrectly, it will never be found. You can create and export custom functions that are callable from any file that requires your schema as follows:

```
userSchema.methods.isPasswordMatched = async function(enteredPassword){
return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
```

};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);